# Inconsistent subscription behaviour in Chrome client

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm registering my clients with a SignalR hub as shown here:

```
        self.connect = () => {
            hub = $.connection.instantMessageHub;
            hub.client.receiveMessage = receiveMessage;
            hub.client.receiveCommand = receiveCommand;
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }
```

In **Chrome**, on initial page load or soft reload (F5) the client does not subscribe to the hub therefore no messages are being received. Turning on logging verifies this i.e. the following line does **not** display:

*[17:12:50 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'instantmessagehub'.*

However doing a hard reload (Ctrl-F5) connects the Chrome client to the hub. This same code works fine in IE and Firefox in all scenarios, and is definitely being hit when the Chrome client fails to subscribe.

So what would be causing this inconsistent hub subscription behaviour in **Chrome**?

Comment: Is that coffeescript? Or ES6?

Answer (score 0):

After stepping through the SignalR code I realised that the connection was being started twice due to calling...

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

... in two separate places as I was trying to initialise two separate hubs.

I chose to merge the two hubs into one in this instance as it made more sense anyway.

I'm unsure why this issue was isolated to Chrome however...